# On what basis are some cricketers knighted?

Tags: cricket

On what basis are some cricketers "knighted". For example Sir Don Bradman, Sir Vivian Richards etc.

Is it because they were "great" cricketers. If thats the logic, there has been so many other great cricketers that haven't been "knighted".

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's about the criteria for the UK & Commonwealth honours system, not about a sport.

Answer (score 3):

Knighthoods and other honours are awarded for "services to sport"; there are no fixed criteria and the award is (nominally) made by the reigning monarch of the UK.

It's also worth noting that while relatively few cricketers have been knighted, a non-trivial number have received other honours (MBEs etc).